# Can I use a subquery inside an INSERT statement?

Tags: mysql, subquery

I need to insert a row into a table, with one field value being calculated from another table. Rather than doing two queries and risking a race condition, I thought it'd be better to do it all in one statement.

```
INSERT INTO `myTable` (`someData`, `averageAtThisTime`)
VALUES (
    "some stuff",
    SELECT AVG(`myField`) FROM `myOtherTable`
)
```

... but this doesn't work. Is there a way I can achieve this in one statement? If not, what's your recommendation?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO `myTable` (`someData`, `averageAtThisTime`)
select "some stuff", AVG(`myField`) 
FROM `myOtherTable`
```

Comment: I didn't know that you cold arbitrary `SELECT` data. Great!!

Answer (score 5):

Your subquery shoud be enclosed in parentheses.
This code should work:

```
INSERT INTO `myTable` (`someData`, `averageAtThisTime`)
VALUES (
"some stuff",
(SELECT AVG(`myField`) FROM `myOtherTable`)
);
```