# Can I use a SELECT subquery inside an INSERT query?

Tags: mysql, subquery

I've tried following the syntax suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/617493/can-i-use-a-subquery-inside-an-insert-statement), but it doesn't work for my query.

Here's what I currently have:

```
INSERT INTO dot (entrant_id, year, entry_code, title, retail_category, campaign_type, client_company, client_city, client_state, field_date_active, height, width, depth, weight, oversize_fee, volt_110, attach_to_gridwall, hang_from_ceiling, table_or_countertop, misc_setup, created_date, modified_date, co_entrant)
        VALUES (288, 2011, 1234, 'RG Total Defense BW mixed Floorstand', '32', 'C', 'Henkel', 'Scottsdale', 'AZ', '2011-01-15', 60, 26, 15, 29, 0, '0', '0', '0', '0', '', NOW(), NOW(), '')
```

However, I need the value of entry_code to be selected from the same table - I can do it as an individual query:

```
MAX(entry_code) FROM dot WHERE year = 2011
```

but can't seem to integrate that with the insert statement. Is this possible? Or will a subquery like that only work if it's selecting from a different table?

Comment: Can you clarify what "doesn't work" means. e.g. record doesn't get inserted without and error. doesn't get inserted with an error, syntax error etc.

Comment: Possibly just a typo in your question, but it should read `SELECT MAX ... WHERE year = '2011'`

Comment: @dbares: year is an int column; you don't need single quotes around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO dot (entrant_id, year, entry_code, ...)
SELECT 288, 2011, MAX(entry_code), ... FROM dot WHERE year=2011
```

Comment: Are you saying the where clause should be at the end, after ALL the other insert values? Like this? `INSERT INTO dot (entrant_id, year, entry_code, ...)
SELECT 288, 2011, MAX(entry_code),'NatureSweet and Build A Better Burger', '32', 'M', 'NatureSweet', 'San Antonio', 'TX', '2011-05-15', 22\", 22\", 0, 0, 0, '0', '0', '0', '0', 'Please see attached pdf for additional 7 instore tactics supporting campaign.', NOW(), NOW(), ''

 FROM dot WHERE year = 2011`

Comment: Because that gives me a big old error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '..) SELECT 288, 2011, MAX(entry_code),'NatureSweet and Build A Better Burger', ' at line 1

Comment: Did you replace the `...` with the actual list of the field names? (I was just using the `...`s to save space in my answer.)

Comment: Yes, I did. But looking at it again, I found a typo in the statement I was using (there were text characters in a column that's int.) So your code does work, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax in the link you provided should work. But that's not the syntax you "currently have" try syntax like this (which is quite similar to that link..):

```
insert into dot(field1, field2, field3, field4) select max(entry_code), 'value2', val3, 'value4' from dot where year = 2011
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO dot (entrant_id, year, entry_code, title, retail_category, campaign_type, client_company, client_city, client_state, field_date_active, height, width, depth, weight, oversize_fee, volt_110, attach_to_gridwall, hang_from_ceiling, table_or_countertop, misc_setup, created_date, modified_date, co_entrant)
VALUES (288, 2011, (SELECT MAX(entry_code) FROM dot WHERE year = 2011), 'RG Total Defense BW mixed Floorstand', '32', 'C', 'Henkel' ...
```